# prefix to infix notation using an recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am new here and I am somehow stuck.
I created an recursive algorithm that uses an global variable for remembering the Position he made the recursive call and I am trying to get rid of this variable as for me it seems to be not a good solution.

Is there any chance to get rid of this global variable? I cannot adjust the method-head so therefore the Interface of the method is fixed.

Here you can see my Code:

```
static int pos = -1;
static boolean writeInfix(char[] expr) {
    boolean result;
    pos++;
    int printpos = pos;
    if(expr[pos]=='+'||expr[pos]=='-'||expr[pos]=='/'||expr[pos]=='*'){
        System.out.print("(");
        writeInfix(expr);
        System.out.print(expr[printpos]);
        result = writeInfix(expr);
        System.out.print(")");
        return result;
    }else if(expr[pos] >= 'a' && expr[pos] <= 'z'){
        System.out.print(expr[pos]);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new auxiliary method, where you control its variables, and let `writeInfix(char[]`) be only a wrapper, that does nothing but calling the "real" method.

In this new method, `pos` is an arument.

- This also ensures you can call your API method (`writeInfix`) twice (independently) without worrying from the side effects (`pos` is initialized with wrong value after first call).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write another method with the position as additional argument:

```
private static boolean writeInfix(char[] expr, int pos) {
    boolean result;
    int printpos = pos;
    if(expr[pos]=='+'||expr[pos]=='-'||expr[pos]=='/'||expr[pos]=='*'){
        System.out.print("(");
        writeInfix(expr);
        System.out.print(expr[printpos]);
        result = writeInfix(expr, pos + 1);
        System.out.print(")");
        return result;
    }else if(expr[pos] >= 'a' && expr[pos] <= 'z'){
        System.out.print(expr[pos]);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in the method you already have, you just need to call

```
static boolean writeInfix(char[] expr) {
    return writeInfix(expr, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add pos as an argument to the `writeInfix` function.

```
static boolean writeInfix(char[] expr, int pos);
```

Whereever you are returning false, return -1. Whereever you are returning true, return the current `pos` value.